What are the singular values of $A - I_n$ such that $A$ is a real, symmetric matrix and $I_n$ is the identity matrix?
Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and symmetric and $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n \times n$.
I want to know how the largest and smallest singular values of $A - I_n$ would behave. Let's assume that singular values are ordered in decreasing order $\sigma_1(A) \geq \sigma_2(A) \geq \sigma_3(A) \cdots \geq \sigma_n(A)$
The first case of interest to me is when $\sigma_i(A) \leq 1$ for all $i$. Then, how should we interpret the singular vectors of $A-I_n$ with respect to that of $A$? With the above logic, the top left/right singular vectors of $A$ will correspond to bottom left\right singular vectors of $A- I_n$, is that correct?
By convention, singular values are positive and in that case, to my understanding, singular values of $A$ should be $1 - \sigma_i(A)$ and the order of singular values is essentially flipped.
Another question is when $\sigma_i(A)$ are arbitrary positive numbers, can I upper bound the spectral norm $\| A - I \| \leq \max_i \lvert \sigma_i(A) - 1 \rvert$? Is there a more meaningful bound?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your formula only works for $\sigma_i \le 1$.
